# Unable to instantiate paypal sdk for multiple configurations

Tags: node.js, paypal-rest-sdk

I have multiple paypal configurations ~15 users

```
[
  ...,
  { environment: "sandbox", accKey: "xxxxx", secretKey: "xxxxxxx" },
  ....  
]
```

I want to instantiate a paypal for each user and return the object

The problem with nodejs is that paypal-rest-sdk export default object, unlike stripe that export stripe

```
// paypal
const paypal = require("paypal-rest-sdk")
paypal.config({ 
// config goes here
})


// stripe
const { Stripe } = require("stripe")
const stripe = new Stripe("secret key")
```

PROBLEM: If I will wrap `paypal.configure` in for-loop it will overwrite the old config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I figured it out myself only.

While executing any request, there is optional second parameter in the functions, passing in new configuration object would override the old configuration set by `.configure` function.

This code has been taken from the official paypal-rest-sdk, original link [here](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-node-SDK/blob/master/samples/configuration/multiple_config.js)

```
var first_config = {
    'mode': 'sandbox',
    'client_id': '<FIRST_CLIENT_ID>',
    'client_secret': '<FIRST_CLIENT_SECRET>'
};

var second_config = {
    'mode': 'sandbox',
    'client_id': '<SECOND_CLIENT_ID>',
    'client_secret': '<SECOND_CLIENT_SECRET>'
};

//This sets up client id and secret globally
//to FIRST_CLIENT_ID and FIRST_CLIENT_SECRET
paypal.configure(first_config);

var create_payment_json = {
    "intent": "authorize",
    "payer": {
        "payment_method": "paypal"
    },
    "redirect_urls": {
        "return_url": "http://return.url",
        "cancel_url": "http://cancel.url"
    },
    "transactions": [{
        "item_list": {
            "items": [{
                "name": "item",
                "sku": "item",
                "price": "1.00",
                "currency": "USD",
                "quantity": 1
            }]
        },
        "amount": {
            "currency": "USD",
            "total": "1.00"
        },
        "description": "This is the payment description."
    }]
};

// Overriding the default configuration with "second_config"
paypal.payment.create(create_payment_json, second_config, function (error, payment) {
    if (error) {
        throw error;
    } else {
        console.log("Create Payment Response");
        console.log(payment);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap into your own module and export it, the key here is wrapping paypal into it own scope

```
// my-paypal-module.js
module.exports = config => {
  const paypal = require("paypal-rest-sdk")
  paypal.configure(config)
  
  return paypal
}


// main-file.js
const Paypal = require('./my-paypal-module')
const paypal = new Paypal({ /* config */ })
```

Comment: Is it good approach to use require in a function?